# How do I resolve this paradox of installing a new operating system?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I used to be an user of windows 7 64 bit version.Later, I installed windows 8 32 bit version. Now, I wish to install windows 8 or windows 10 64 bit version for some technical reasons. I have some very important files stored in my pc. I have only one hard disk drive C of 400 GB. I'm told that when I install windows 64 bit, my all data in C will be cleared. So, I want to create a new hard disk which I can stores all my files to. As I've no experience of doing partition, I am thinking of two ways- using windows command window or using a free partition manager. When I partition of my disk space of 400GB, is there any chance of data getting erased up or lost during it- in both the methods?

Comment: Windows Setup never destroys anything unless you explicitly click the “Format” or “Delete partition” buttons.

Comment: I strongly advice that you start by backing up your important files on an external drive (hdd/usb stick) and/or an online storage before doing anything

Comment: As Daniel B says, you can most likely install windows onto the same partition that windows is already installed on, and everything should be automatically moved to the `Windows.old` directory. The GUI installer should do this all automatically. You may need to click on a button for "advanced" or "custom" disk options.

Comment: There is always a chance of something going wrong no matter how careful you are. That's why you should have backups. You do have backups, right?

Answer (score 2):

You have an easier route you can take.

If you've never partitioned a hard drive before, don't learn how when you have critical data at stake, there's a really high chance you'll lose at least some data learning how it all works.

The easier option would be to just install windows onto the same partition with your data. As long as you have enough free space (~15GB) available, you won't lose anything.

Read [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824910.aspx) page before you try the following method, some commands will require you to supply system-specific information.

It's pretty easy to do, boot your Windows 10 installation media. Once you have control of the mouse and keyboard, don't follow any menus.

Press Shift + F10 to open a command prompt.

Create a directory in C: for all the old stuff to go in.

```
md C:\OldWindows
```

Move everything into this new directory.

```
robocopy C:\ C:\OldWindows\ /xd OldWindows /move /sl /copyall /e
```

Install windows 10

```
dism /apply-image /imagefile:\sources\install.wim /index:1 /applydir:C:\
```

Set up boot files

```
C:\Windows\system32\bcdboot C:\Windows /l en-US
```